# Turning my website into a non-profit

Tags: legal, non-profit

I was given an established website about a year ago. It makes some money on ads, but not much (less than 10k/year). I am no longer able to manage the site and am considering turning it over to another person.

I don't want them to turn around and sell it. It was suggested that I establish a non-profit of sorts and transfer the assets to that entity. Does anybody have experience or advice on this subject?

Comment: Which country are you based in?

Comment: If its actually making money, why dont you consider selling it?

Comment: I am in the US. I am considering selling it, but in the event I cannot find a buyer, I would be willing to transfer it to an individual within the website's community in order to avoid shutting the site down.

Comment: Transferring to a nonprofit that has an aligned mission would be the better bet. Setting up a nonprofit (as someone who has done this for a website) is likely going to involved as much or more overhead for you than running the site, depending on your current workload for it. I'd suggest you look for an established organization that seems like they could continue the program/site.

Comment: Shameless non-profit plug: http:onefortheorphan.com

Answer (score 2):

In what country? the USA? I've heard from several people that establishing a formal non-profit organization is a *lot* of complicated paperwork and setup.

It might be easier to

- simply donate the money to a charity
- possibly donate the *website* to a charity, if they can handle that
- sell the website yourself
- shut the website down

Comment: Yes, it's in the US. From what I've read so far, it does indeed seem to be very complicated, and possibly may not even qualify. I am reluctant to sell it, but that may end up being the best option.